# Block All User Input when iteracting with server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have some actions that interact with the server and take some time...  i'm trying to block all form fields in a page when i'm interacting with the server... I thought of finding all controls in a page dynamically and setting enabled=false inside update panels and enabling them again when finished.. but I don't think that this is the best way to do this... Anyone who've already did this? any suggestions?

Comment: Usually, just disabling the submit button(s) is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) JQuery plugin.